How can I change the inlay hints keyboard shortcut in Visual Studio Code?
By default, the keyboard shortcut for parameter/type hints inlay is CTRL+ALT.
I could not find a way to change this keyboard shortcut in the Keyboard Shortcuts editor.
In my Settings, I have set Editor > Inlay Hints: Enabled to offUnlessPressed.
This means that pressing the keyboard shortcut (CTRL+ALT) will momentarily enable the showing of type and parameter hints.

It's an open feature-request: Allow cusomizing the hotkey that shows/hides inlay hints #149019. Posted by none other than HolyBlackCat.
I suggest that you give that issue ticket a thumbs up to show support for it. You can also subscribe to it to get notified about discussion and progress. Please avoid making noisy comments there like ones that just consist of "+1" / "bump".
For your reference / learning purposes, I found this by googling "site:github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues inlay hints "offUnlessPressed" "feature-request"".
